# How to explain "Propositions are sets of worlds"?

Tags: semantics, theoretical-linguistics

According to Kratzer, propositions are sets of worlds, but I find it really abstract. Are there any examples to explain it?

Comment: I would have thought that from a possible worlds perspective, referring to the set of worlds in which apples are red is the same thing as saying "apples are red", because those worlds cannot logically have anything else in common (except for things that follow automatically from the fact that they are worlds, or the fact that apples are red). In other words, every proposition will correspond to a unique set of possible worlds, and vice versa.

Comment: Since there is only one world, it's impossible to provide an "example" of a different possible world. One might try to *explain* what it means: you could read Kripke 1972 "Naming and Necessity", which involves a telescope.

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact, Angelika Kratzer explains it very clearly on pp. 10-11 (example 6) in her 2012 book *Modals and Conditionals* https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199234684.001.0001/acprof-9780199234684

Comment: @rchivers Thank you for your explanation! Now I totally get it!

Comment: Very brief explanation: A possible world is a very large hypothetical or actual situation situation; a proposition is then the collection of all those situations in which it is true. Think of possible worlds as parallel universes if you like.

Comment: @lemontree♦ Thank you for your explanation so much!